# Write in the canonical form the expression $ab+bc+ca-a+b$

Tags: linear-algebra, canonical-transformation

Write in the canonical form the expression
$$ab+bc+ca-a+b$$

---

First, I tried to eliminate the lonely terms, but seems like quite impossible:
$$a(b'+1) + b(c'-1) + (c'-1)a - a + b = ab'+bc'+c'a-a$$
It is going to get me into an "infinite loop" if I keep trying to get rid of them.

Still if I am to write this as follows
$$(a+b+c)^2-ab-bc-ca-a+b=(a+b+c)^2+\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2+\frac{1}{2}(b-c)^2+\frac{1}{2}(c-a)^2-\\-a^2-b^2-c^2-a+b$$
I don't get anything useful.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

your original can be written as half of the diagonal matrix below with $Q$ as coefficients, thus

$$ \left( \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2} +  c \right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} (-a+b -2)^2 - c^2 + 1 $$

The thing cannot be accomplished without a constant inside one of the squares as in $(-a+b-2)^2$

What we actually do is add in a new variable to make the thing homogeneous quadratic,

$$ab+bc+ca-ad+bd$$

My matrix $H$ is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Could you please give some reference to get familiarized? Maybe Wiki or something...